# how to write an installer along with database file?

Tags: c#, installation

I am writing a c# application.And there i,m using a SQLite database to store data than handled in my application.Now I want to write an Installer to install the application in another computer.There I want to create the database file automatically in the installation process and update the connection string also.

I could create a setup file using visual studio 2005.But I couldn't create the database.And also I want to know how to copy an existing database file to a given folder in the installation process.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you can create a "setup" project for your application and in this project you can add your SQLite file to be copied with the rest of the files
Here is link of how to create a setup project [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c#-application-visual-studio-setup-project/)